# Best way to store data during runtime

Tags: android

I am currently working on a vocabulary trainer for android smartphones. There will be hundreds of index cards that are going to be used by **multiple** activities. It would be **too expensive** to load all index cards from database each time a new activity needs them. Sometimes an activity **modifies a index card**. The modification should be visible too all other activities.

***Question:***

All index card are stored in an ArrayList of type IndexCard. Should I store it in a class extending from *Application* or should I rather pass the whole ArrayList to activities using bundles?

This blog tells me, that my first idea would be no good practice, http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/

What way is the more efficient and what is good practice?

Comment: I'd look at your architecture.  Do you actually need to load all the index cards at the beginning?  Or can you do something with lazy loading of data from the database, loading each index card as you need it?

Comment: As the vocabulary trainer offers an option just to train all existing index cards, i need to be sure that all of them are available. Lazy loading would infer more database access which could end up in performance lost.

Comment: But do they actually do that frequently enough that its worth taking a constant memory and performance hit everywhere instead of just doing so when they actually wish to hit all index cards at once?  Especially since you'll then need to write them out to the db again at the end of the operation (or risk losing the changes) so you'll be hitting the db anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i prefer storing it into the database as you already mentioned and loading it in the first start to an Map which holds serialized Objects. You can also store the serialized Objects and keep an index in the Database. So you will only need to load the indexes and have an reference to the serialized Object as soon as you need it. Accessing those files should be by far faster then reading the database.

Storing thise in a SingleTon Object is not a good idea, since the GC will destroy it and/or the application pretty fast in this case.   Those called "Soft-References" are the best way. If you really want to store a huge collection of data (which i dont prefer) you may want to use vanilla-java https://code.google.com/p/vanilla-java/wiki/HugeCollections

Comment: Thanks! So you pass the map through your app, e.g. when starting a new activity? Is it more efficient to save serialized objects than querying the database?

Comment: You can send the ArrayList in a Bundle and/or the serialized Object in an Intent to the new Activity. And yes, it depends on the numer of Objects. Usually SQLite is very fast but serializing those files and storing only a reference should be faster.

Comment: Ok, i implemented your proposed way and it seems to be performant.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about storing it in SharedPreferences?  I also have a rather large XML data file (250k) in my app.  During app launch, I read the data file into an ArrayList of custom object, serialize the ArrayList, and store it as String in SharedPreferences.  I used Gson library and it's very quick and easy to store and load ArrayList objects as string.

Comment: I hesitate using SharedPreferences, because they pursue another goal. I don't want to misuse them.